# Return countdown array javascript logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my logic here? I'm trying to return an array that counts down from the number input to the function. As of now, I'm getting an empty array, as opposed to `[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]` (the expected result).

```js
const countDown = (number) => {
  let arrayCount = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    arrayCount.push(number.length - i)
  }
  return arrayCount
}


console.log(countDown(7));
```

Comment: `number.length` Numbers don't have `.length`s. You just want `number`

Comment: Ahh of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `number.length` (numbers don't have a `length` property), you should just use `number` in both places. Also, inside your for loop specification, use `<= number` or else you'll be off by one.

```js
const countDown = (number) => {
  let arrayCount = [];
  for(let i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
      arrayCount.push(number - i)
  }
return arrayCount
}


console.log(countDown(7));
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is to reverse the keys of an array.

```js
const countDown = number => [...Array(number + 1).keys()].reverse();
console.log(countDown(7));
```